# Solidity: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting

Tags: solidity, nft, brownie

When I try to run:

```
 brownie run scripts/collectible/deploy_advanced.py --network rinkeby
```

this error occurs...

```
   INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
    Brownie v1.14.6 - Python development framework for Ethereum
    
NftProject is the active project.
  File "c:\users\hello\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "c:\users\hello\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 43, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "c:\users\hello\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 40, in connect
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File "c:\users\hello\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 52, in connect
    uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
  File "c:\users\hello\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 183, in _expand_environment_vars
    raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
```

and here is my code

```
from brownie import MyCollectible, accounts, network, config
#from scripts.helpful_scripts import  fund_advanced_collectible

def main():
    ##Deploying the NFT
    theAcc = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(str({theAcc})+" "+str({network.show_active()}))
    publish_source = False
    myCollectible = MyCollectible.deploy(
        #Selecting network for deploy the thing
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['vrf_coordinator'],
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['link_token'],
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['keyhash'],
        {"from":theAcc},
        publish_source=config['wallets']['WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID']


        
    ) 
    def fund_advanced_collectible(nft_contract):
    theAcc = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    link_token = interface.LinkTokenInterface(
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['link_token'])

    link_token.transfer(nft_contract, 100000000000000000, {'from':theAcc})
    fund_advanced_collectible(myCollectible)
    return myCollectible
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102807/eth-brownie-unable-to-expand-environment-variable-in-host-setting

Answer (score 1):

create `brownie-config.yaml` in root of your project or your home folder

> The configuration file must be saved as brownie-config.yaml. If saved in >the root directory of a project it will be loaded whenever that project is >active. If saved in your home path, it will always be loaded.

use the [brownie docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html?#default-configuration) to get the default config file and paste it into the yaml file you created, with the addition of this line

```
dotenv: .env
```

create a file named `.env` in your project's root folder and place the following line with your infura id

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=<YOUR_INFURA_ID>
```

save the file, try deploying again