# eth-brownie: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting

Tags: python, brownie

When running a script:

```bash
brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network kovan
```

I receive this error:

```bash
raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: ‘{uri}’”)
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: ‘https://kovan.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically, this means your environment variables are not set correctly, and it looks like in this case it's your `WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID`.

### Solution 1

You can fix it by setting the variable in your `.env` file and adding `dotenv: .env` to your `brownie-config.yaml`.

`brownie-config.yaml`:

```
dotenv: .env
```

`.env`:

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE
```

Remember to save these files.

Additionally, you should be on at least brownie version v1.14.6. You can find out what version you're on with:

```
brownie --version
```

---

### Solution 2

If you know how to [set environment variables](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html) you might want to check if you're setting them correctly. If you're on a linux-like environment, you can do:

```
source .env
```

To set them.

Comment: Hi, where do you find all the possible env variable fro brownie? I mean, How can someone know about the existance of `WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID`?

Comment: You'll have it in your .env file. You don't want others to be able to see that file though, otherwise they could make API calls to infura.

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm asking how do you know that that KEY has a meaning for brownie, I mean, in the documentation I can't find reference to that env Key

Comment: Good question, it's built in to brownie. Check here: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.1/config.html?highlight=WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID#the-configuration-file

Comment: Thank you, i really have those env variable that are hidden and not documented (e.g. `ETHERSCAN_TOKEN` that is used to publish the source code in etherscan, it's not reported)

Comment: Hi Patrick Collin. Do I only need to add Private_key and WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID in .evn or I also need to add them to my computer environment variable? I did it with .evn file but I get the same error" ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID' "

Comment: Try doing it in your `.env` file instead of `.evn`.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this error for days and have seen it posted alot online.
I was simply 1 directory up from where I needed to be - I followed the Patrick Collins tutorial very closey with the addition of setting up a virtual env, so maybe others are simply having the same problem I had.

I was originally in a directory "\demos\web3 brownie" which contained a folder called "brownie" and my python virtual env files.

The script is now running when I'm in directory "\demos\web3 brownie\brownie" which contains the brownie build, script, contract directories

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can be as simple as a typo error, such as improperly naming your files, such as "browni-config.yaml" when it should be "brownie-config.yaml".

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure you set the .env correctly you can try sourcing your .env file in the terminal:

```
source .env
```

and then try running your script again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you , also with PRIVATE_KEY associating. What I've done is copy the .env field in the scripts folder , adding also dotenv : .env to brownie-config.yaml